# css margin and padding newbie question

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

I'm struggling to under the behaviour of the following html and css code.  I'm aware of box layouts and margin collapsing but it doesn't seem to explain the following:

1) Using the code below, unmodified, the logo is shown with about 10px of white space between it and the top of the page and about 4 or 5 pixels below but of the color given by #allcontent.background-color.  Interestingly if I set the font-size property within the body to 0px this removes all the white space above the logo and the 4 or 5 pixels below it.

2) If the padding value within #allcontent is changed from 0px to 1px then about 10px of padding is actually added above and below the logo with the color specified by the #allcontent.background-color.

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css" />
    </head> 

    <body>
        <div id="allcontent">
        <div id="header">           
            <p>
            <img width="200" height="60" src="images/logo.gif" alt="Logo" />
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

my.css file:

```
body {      
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#allcontent{
    background-color: #dddddd;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;    
}

#header {   
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your code: http://jsbin.com/eronaq

Starting with the easier issue:

> the logo is shown with [..] about 4 or
>   5 pixels below

That gap is the space reserved for the descenders in text for letters like `g` and `p`.

You can fix that in a few ways. For example, by setting `display: block` or `vertical-align` to `top` or `bottom` on the `img`.

`display: block`: http://jsbin.com/eronaq/2

> the logo is shown with about 10px of
>   white space between it and the top of
>   the page

**See:** http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

That space is the `margin-top` on the `p` collapsing through all the way up to `body`, because there is nothing to stop it doing as defined by the rules of collapsing margins.

> By “touch,” we mean the places at
>   which no padding, borders, or content
>   exist between the adjacent margins.